# Pass the value of a variable from subdomain to domain using localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser, local-storage

I have a task in which I need to transfer the value of a variable from a subdomain to a domain. I am using `localstorage`. I have a domain, and I have a subdomain, which means that each has its own script file, template file, etc.

In the subdomain script file, I write the following, i.e. I put the value of the variable into the localstorage cell:

/*subdomain script file*/

```
localStorage.setItem("city_id", city_id);
```

In the domain script file, I am trying to get this value like this:

/*domain script file*/

```
var result = localStorage.getItem("city_id");
console.log(result);
```

But the console displays `undefined`.

Has already worked with localstorage, and more than once. But one thing is not clear to me, if this is a browser storage, then there is no difference where you enter the value, and where you try to get it (I'm talking about different script files).

Maybe I missed something, or I don't fully understand how localstorage works. If localstorage does not work that way, please tell me other methods of transferring the value of a variable from a subdomain to a domain, or vice versa. Thank.

Comment: could be the local storage respects cookie rules on sub domains

Comment: As such, you could implement your own "local storage cache" server side.

Comment: LocalStorage does not allow data to be shared from different domains. There are solutions available like [cross-domain-local-storage](https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage) or you can [use cookies that are shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/2713655) between the two domains.